# Дефисное написание существительных и прилагательных

Tags: слитно-дефис

Подскажите пожалуйста, как надо писать следующие слова: моменто-приложение, диаметро-сберегающий, пространство-сберегающий?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все слова пишутся слитно.

Моментоприложение - сложное существительное пишется слитно при наличии соединительной гласной (если такое слово существует вообще). Дефисное написание в этом случае является исключением.

Диаметросберегающий, пространствосберегающий - сложные прилагательные, способ образования - чистое сложение. Сравнить: энергосберегающий.

Comment: Сберегающий энергию, сберегающий пространство... Т. е. словосочетания с подчинительной связью? Поняла, спасибо.

Comment: С дефисом "моменто-приложение" воспринимается своеобразно: я сначала подумал, что это итальянская компьютерная программа (то ли быстрого использования, то ли от фирмы Momento) :).

Comment: Я ее тоже встретила в интернете, когда пыталась найти случаи употребления этого существительного. Только там по-моему Memento. Или и то и другое. :)

Comment: Memento имеет глагольный смысл: 'memento mori' - помни о смерти (лат.)